# JavaFX with fxml TableView updating some columns but not others

Tags: javafx, tableview, fxml, updating

In my application Some of the columns in my table are populating like they should be the columns labeled Name Priority and BurstTime have the correct values being added but for some reason the other two ProcessID and State do not update with the values I am adding to my ArrayList.

It looks like my code should be working can anybody see something I have missed?

[image]

Here is my controller

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;



import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

private ArrayList<String> buf = new ArrayList<>();

protected ArrayList<PCB> array = new ArrayList<>();
protected ArrayList<Process> arrayP = new ArrayList<>();

ObservableList<Process> processData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


@FXML
private Button SubmitButton;

@FXML
private Button LoadButton;


@FXML
private TextArea textArea;

@FXML
private TextField inputBox;

@FXML
private TableView<Process> ProcessTable;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Process, String> processIDP;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Process, String> processTypeP;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Process, String> priorityCodeP;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Process, String> burstTimeP;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Process, String> StatusCodeP;



@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    processIDP.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Process, String>("processIDP"));
    processTypeP.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Process, String>("processTypeP"));
    priorityCodeP.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Process, String>("priorityCodeP"));
    burstTimeP.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Process, String>("burstTimeP"));
    StatusCodeP.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Process, String>("StatusCodeP"));

    Process p1 = new Process();
    p1.setprocessIDP("22");
    p1.setProcessTypeP ("Apname");
    p1.setPriorityCodeP("1");
    p1.setBurstTimeP ("13");
    p1.setstatusCodeP("Tada");

    arrayP.add(p1);
    ProcessTable.getItems().addAll(arrayP.get(0));

    ProcessTable.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(arrayP));

    Process p2 = new Process();
    p2.setprocessIDP("24");
    p2.setProcessTypeP ("Bpname");
    p2.setBurstTimeP ("15");
    p2.setPriorityCodeP("2");

    arrayP.add(p2);
    ProcessTable.getItems().addAll(arrayP.get(1));

    // edit existing cell ?
    arrayP.get(1).setPriorityCodeP("8");
    arrayP.get(1).setstatusCodeP("This");
    arrayP.get(1).setprocessIDP("TEST");

}

public ObservableList<Process> getProcessData() {
    return processData;
}


@FXML
private TextField LoadProgram;

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction() {
    textArea.appendText(inputBox.getText() + "\n");
    StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(inputBox.getText(), " ");

    switch(st1.nextToken()) {
    // case "proc": proc(); break;
     case "mem": textArea.appendText("Memory: " + String.valueOf(Memory.getUsedMemory()) + "/" + String.valueOf(Memory.getTotalMemory()) + "\n"); break;
    // case "exe": exe(); break;
    // case "reset": reset(); break;
     case "load": buf.add(inputBox.getText()) ;
       // edit existing cell ?
       arrayP.get(1).setPriorityCodeP("9");

       ProcessTable.refresh();

       break;
     case "exit": System.exit(0); break;
     case "clear": textArea.clear(); break;
     default: break;
 }
}




@FXML
private void handleLoadAction() {
    File infile = new File("files/" + LoadProgram.getText() + ".txt");
    if (infile.exists() == true ) {
        textArea.appendText("Loading " + LoadProgram.getText() + "\n");
        }

    //call to read data here

    else {
    textArea.appendText("No Program named " + LoadProgram.getText() + " found \n");
}}



public class textLine {


    private String infile;
    private String cmd, value;
    private Scanner input;


    public void parseFile(String filename) {
        this.infile = "files/" + filename + ".txt";
        parseFile();
    }

    public void addbuf(String textline) {
        buf.add(textline);
    }

    private void parseFile() {

        buf.clear();
        try {
            File file = new File(infile);
            if (file.exists() == true)
            input = new Scanner(file);
            while (input.hasNext()) {
                buf.add(input.next());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        input.close();
    }

}

}
```

Here is my class for Procsess

```
package application;


public class Process {

String processTypeP = "";
String priorityCodeP = "0";
int lineCodeP = 0;
String burstTimeP = "0";
String processIDP = "0";
String StatusCodeP = "0";

public Process (){} 

public String getProcessTypeP() {
    return processTypeP;
}
public void setProcessTypeP(String processTypeP) {
    this.processTypeP = processTypeP;
}

public String getPriorityCodeP() {
    return priorityCodeP;
}
public void setPriorityCodeP(String priorityCodeP) {
    this.priorityCodeP = priorityCodeP;
}

public int getLineCodeP() {
    return lineCodeP;
}
public void setLineCodeP(int lineCodeP) {
    this.lineCodeP = lineCodeP;
}

public String getBurstTimeP() {
    return burstTimeP;
}
public void setBurstTimeP(String burstTimeP) {
    this.burstTimeP = burstTimeP;
}

     public String getprocessIDP() {
    return processIDP;
}
public void setprocessIDP(String processIDP) {
    this.processIDP = processIDP;
}

    public String getstatusCodeP() {
    return StatusCodeP;
}
public void setstatusCodeP(String StatusCodeP) {
    this.StatusCodeP = StatusCodeP;
}



}
```

Here is my main application

```
package application;



import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javafx.scene.Scene;


import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;



public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/Main.fxml"));
    //  Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Main.fxml"));
        AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) loader.load(Main.class.getResource("/application/Main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

and my fxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
<children>
<TabPane layoutX="4.0" layoutY="4.0" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="900.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
    <tabs>
      <Tab text="Processes">
        <content>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                 <children>
                    <TextField fx:id="inputBox" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="54.0" />
                    <Button fx:id="SubmitButton" layoutX="109.0" layoutY="94.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Submit" />
                    <TextArea fx:id="textArea" layoutX="197.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="105.0" prefWidth="493.0" />
                    <TableView fx:id="ProcessTable" layoutX="36.0" layoutY="157.0" prefHeight="430.0" prefWidth="654.0">
                      <columns>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="processIDP" prefWidth="75.0" text="ProccessID" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="processTypeP" prefWidth="101.0" text="Name" />
                          <TableColumn fx:id="priorityCodeP" prefWidth="94.0" text="Priority" />
                          <TableColumn fx:id="StatusCodeP" prefWidth="119.0" text="State" />
                          <TableColumn fx:id="burstTimeP" prefWidth="100.0" text="BurstTime" />
                      </columns>
                    </TableView>
                    <TextField fx:id="LoadProgram" layoutX="712.0" layoutY="492.0" />
                    <Button fx:id="LoadProgramButton" layoutX="725.0" layoutY="531.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleLoadAction" text="Load External Program" />
                 </children></AnchorPane>
        </content>
      </Tab>
      <Tab text="Scheduler">
        <content>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
        </content>
      </Tab>
        <Tab text="Memory">
           <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
           </content>
        </Tab>
    </tabs>
  </TabPane>
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try renaming your getter methods from `getprocessIDP` and `getstatusCodeP` to `getProcessIDP` and `getStatusCodeP` respectively (note the capital 'S' and 'P'). To avoid problems like this in the future it's a good habit to generate getters, setters and constructors with the IDE instead of doing it manually.

Comment: You were right THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!! was pulling my hair out